# How to get entire http response using Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 and I want to set **session-id** and **csrf-token** to cookies.
So I need to get these two from http response. But when I send a request using **HttpClient** I just receive body of the response in subscribe method.
So what do I need to do?

Authentication.service.ts:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private BASE_URL = 'http://192.168.1.12:8000/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  signIn(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + 'api/auth/', user)
      .subscribe((resp: Response) => {
        console.log(resp.headers);
      });
  }
}
```

Authentication.component.ts:

```
export class AuthenticationComponent implements OnInit {
  private body;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.body = {
      username: 'foo',
      password: 'foo'
    };
  }

  logIn() {
    this.authService.signIn(this.body);
  }
```

## Update:

here's my response from server:

[response screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH82i.png)

and what i'm taking from console log:

[console log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofaZx.png)

Comment: Can you show how's your resp looks like ??

Comment: it'll be automatically set under cookies, as soon as it's returned from server, have you checked under cookies?

Comment: Yes it returned as a cookie but it didn't set to browser cookies. I want to access headers to set them to cookies

Answer (score 0):

You've to check if the server (back-end) has included these two headers in the property - [Response.headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers), for the POST request you're performing. You can perform this check from the front-end code as well. Change your *signIn* method like this:

```
  signIn(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + 'api/auth/', user)
      .subscribe((resp: Response) => {
        console.log(resp.headers);
      });
  }
```

Check in the console statement if these two properties (session-id and csrf-token) are present in the headers object.